# Java IntStream, Range and mapToDouble and reduce function equivalent in C#

Tags: java, c#

Can someone help me with what will the below lines of Java do ? Or can you give an C# equivalent of the below lines of code

```
  public static double[] logSumExp(List<Double> a, List<Double> b) {
    double amax = Collections.max(a);
    double sum = IntStream.range(0, a.size())
                     .mapToDouble(i -> Math.exp(a.get(i) - amax) * (i < b.size() ? b.get(i) : 1.0))
                     .reduce(0.0, Double::sum);
    double sign = Math.signum(sum);
    sum *= sign;
    double abs = Math.log(sum) + amax;
    double[] ret = {abs, sign};
    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

Comment: I want the C# equivalent code of the above code. That would be very helpful. I tried reading the documentation but couldn't understand much.

Comment: Above, `IntStream.range(0, a.size())` basically provides a stream of ints going from `0` to `a.size()` (exclusive). Streams in Java are comparable to IEnumerable in .NET, I believe. `mapToDouble` converts those `int`s to `double`s by raising *e* to the power of `a.get(i) - amax) * (i < b.size() ? b.get(i) : 1.0)`. This part `reduce(0.0, Double::sum)` just adds all those doubles up.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! This should be helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code using streams in Java usually translates well into LINQ in .NET.

`map` or `mapToXXX` works like `Select`, `reduce` is `Aggregate`, but here `Sum` is more convenient. `IntStream.range` is `Enumerable.Range`. Everything else should have a "obvious" equivalent.

```
public static double[] LogSumExp(IList<double> a, IList<double> b) {
    double amax = a.Max();
    double sum = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Count)
                    .Select(i => Math.Exp(a[i] - amax) * (i < b.Count ? b[i] : 1.0))
                    .Sum();
    double sign = Math.Sign(sum);
    sum *= sign;
    double abs = Math.Log(sum) + amax;
    double[] ret = {abs, sign};
    return ret;
}
```

If you are using C# 7+, you should really be returning a tuple instead:

```
public static (double abs, double sign) LogSumExp(IList<double> a, IList<double> b) {
    ...
    return (abs, sign);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The long answer to what that function does is well explained in this [LogSumExp Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp). It's usually referred to by its short name, LSE, or softmax.

The link also explains why the need to subtract the max from each value before applying the exponent and adding the max at the end.

Regarding Java/C# conversion, Java Streams operations are very similar to LINQ operations. For this specific case, the literal conversion should be straightforward as almost all methods are named the same (mind the naming conventions).

The less obvious ones:

- `Collections.max` is a simple LINQ extension method named `Max` that can be applied directly to lists.
- `IntStream` is simply `Enumerable` and has a method `Range` as well.
- `mapToDouble` be achieved in LINQ with `Select`.
- `reduce`, in this case, can be replaced by `Sum`.

Hope you find this information useful.

Answer (score -1):

The C# equivalent code.

```
    public static double[] logSumExp(List<Double> a, List<Double> b)
    {
        double amax = a.Max();
        double sum = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Count()).Sum(i => Math.Exp(a[i] - amax) * (i < b.Count() ? b[i] : 1.0));
        double sign = Math.Sign(sum);
        sum *= sign;
        double abs = Math.Log(sum) + amax;
        double[] ret = {abs, sign};
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: You blatantly copied Sweeper's answer (except you added one mistake). Didn't you even glance at the existing answers?